# Getting the sum of a value for two seperate date ranges in same column and in a single MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table like below and i'm trying to write single query for fetch the date range data as well as sum of price. My table definitions are as below

**Sale table**

```
id_sale date       time
  1     2014-05-05 12.30 am  
  2     2014-05-06 10.30 am 
  3     2014-05-25 12.30 am
```

**Sale Product table**

```
   id_sale_product id_sale price  quantity  id_product
      1              1     10.00   1           1
      2              1     20.00   1           2
      3              2     20.00   3           5
      4              3     20.00   4           6
```

I want to filter by date in sale table and get the sum of the price * quantity = total for every date ie,2014-05-05,2014-05-06..etc

I have tried below query

```
$query = 'SELECT sp.`id_product_type`,sp.`id_product`,sp.`quantity`,sp.`price`,s.`date`
              , SUM(IF(s.`date` BETWEEN "'.$datepickerFrom.'" AND "'.$datepickerTo.'",sp.`price` * sp.`quantity`,0)) AS A
              FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'sale_product` sp
              LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'sales s ON (sp.id_sale = s.id_sale) 
              WHERE (s.`date` BETWEEN "'.$datepickerFrom.'" AND "'.$datepickerTo.'")';
```

The output should be :

```
Example: Date
01/01/2013    Rs.10000
02/01/2013    Rs.140000
03/01/2013    Rs.8000

Example: Month
January     Rs. 2,00,000
Feburary    Rs. 2,20,000
```

Comment: Are you looking for the `group by` statement?

Comment: Your example output doesn't seem to have any relationship to your example input. That makes it impossible to be sure how you want your records processed. Please make your input match your expected output.

Comment: The `IF` statement inside your SUM is made completely redundant by your where clause (there have the same predicate), you may as well just use `SUM(sp.\`price\` * sp.\`quantity\`)`

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Answer (score 0):

Try This ....

```
select a.date,sum(b.qty * b.price) As sum from sales As a, product As b where DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%d-%m-%Y') between '27-05-2014' AND '28-05-2014' and a.id_sale=b.id_sale group by a.date
```