# How to get the sum of values by month vice using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to get sum of total price from the below tables by month from to month to .Example : Jan to Mar How to get the name of the month as well sum of the particular month total. I totally confused with this.Anyone please help me. I'm passing the input like '04-2014' to '05-2014'

**Sale table**

```
id_sale date       time
  1     2014-05-05 12.30 am  
  2     2014-05-06 10.30 am 
  3     2014-05-25 12.30 am
```

**Sale Product table**

```
   id_sale_product id_sale price  quantity  id_product
      1              1     10.00   1           1
      2              1     20.00   1           2
      3              2     20.00   3           5
      4              3     20.00   4           6
```

I want to filter by date in sale table and get the sum of the price * quantity = total for every date ie,2014-05-05,2014-05-06..etc

I have tried below query

```
$query = 'SELECT sp.`id_product_type`,sp.`id_product`,sp.`quantity`,sp.`price`,s.`date`,SUM(sp.`price` * sp.`quantity`) AS total
              FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'sale_product` sp
              LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'sales s ON (sp.id_sale = s.id_sale) 
              WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.`date`, "%m-%Y") BETWEEN "'.$monthFrom.'" AND "'.$monthTo.'"';
```

The output should be :

```
Example: Month
January Rs. 2,00,000
Feburary    Rs. 2,20,000
```

Comment: The main problem with your query is that you do not have a GROUP BY clause. Hence MySQL carries out the SUM operation over all the rows, and returns a single row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the sum of a value for two seperate date ranges in same column and in a single MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934860/getting-the-sum-of-a-value-for-two-seperate-date-ranges-in-same-column-and-in-a)

Answer (score -1):

This query should help:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.date, "%M-%Y"),SUM(sp.`price` * sp.`quantity`) AS total
FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'sale_product` sp
LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'sales s ON (sp.id_sale = s.id_sale) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s.`date`, "%m-%Y") BETWEEN "'.$monthFrom.'" AND "'.$monthTo.'"';
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(s.date, "%M-%Y")
```